# dimplejs - Toggling the display of a series selectively

Tags: dimple.js

To the Word-Awesomeness example in dimplejs documentation,  I have added 2 series with `dimple.plot.bar` and `dimple.plot.line` plotFunctions as shown below:

Chart with 2 series:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
     var data = [
       { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
       { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
     ];
     var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
     chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
     chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
     chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
     chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
     chart.draw();
   </script>
</body>
```

This displays the chart with both line and bar. I would like to hide/show the line and bar based on user selection. I tried removing a series using `chart.series.splice (0,1)` and redrawing. That did not work. The chart always shows both bar and line series.

However, the documentation of `dimple.chart.series` states that:

> This collection is provided for viewing series which have been added with the addSeries method.  However it may be modified directly to remove or move a series.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> // Add three series and remove the middle one using a standard JavaScript array operation
> myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
> myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bubble);
> myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.line);
> myChart.series.splice(1, 1);
> ```

Please let me know how to hide/show a series selectively in dimplejs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chart.draw` code doesn't remove old series from the chart, splicing out the series will just prevent it from being updated the next time you call draw. You'll have to manually remove the elements from the chart :

```
  myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
  myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bubble);
  myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.line);
  chart.series[1].shapes.remove();
  chart.series.splice(1, 1);
```

Here are some other options for toggling series :

1. http://jsbin.com/sacaze/3/edit?css,js,output

   - Add and remove the series each time. The loop to find the series can vary depending on how you're generating the series, it could just look for a specific combination of `dimple.series.plot` and `dimple.series.categoryFields`.
2. http://jsbin.com/sacaze/4/edit?html,js,output

   - Use the same logic to find the series, but just hide/show the shapes instead of removing the series. For toggling this is probably the approach I'd use.

To find the series you could also add a custom key to each series object :

```
var mySeries = chart.addSeries('category', dimple.plot.bar);
mySeries.my_custom_key = 'barSeries';

//somewhere else...
var barSeries = _.find(chart.series, function(series){ return series.my_custom_key === 'barSeries' });
```

Just make sure it doesn't conflict with a key on dimple.series : https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/objects/series/begin.js

Comment: Thanks. I could now remove a series from the display and from the `chart.series` array. However, to simulate toggling (show/hide), position of the series will keep changing whenever it is added back to the `chart.series` array. Of course, one can keep track of the position through a map with a key to every series. Just wondering if there is a simpler way of achieving toggling of a series??!!

Comment: Thanks again. 2nd approach is what I exactly was looking for. That keeps the position of the series in the list intact. This is important, as you can see that the line over bar looks bit different once you hide and show using 1st approach. Also, thanks for the tips on the logic to find the series.