# D3 error when adding a serie in dimple JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

Good day,

In a JS module using dimple.js, I try to make an add/remove trend feature.

The way it is done, I add/remove series.

The add code is:

```
chart.addSeries(tag_list[i].name, dimple.plot.line)
```

The remove code is:

```
//Remove already drawn points.
chart.series[i].shapes.remove();
//Remove from series array.
chart.series.splice(i,1);
```

The add part works fine. The remove part as well.

However, whenever I try to add again a serie previously deleted, i get a D3 error, about selecting the new series:

```
Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN".    
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '.dimple-marker.dimple-series-1.' is not a valid selector.
```

Here is a fiddle that reproduces the issue; http://jsbin.com/lezigoheyo/edit?js,output
First click on toggle adds a new trend. Second click removes it. Third triggers the bug.

This leads me to believe that I have some bad data somewhere, which prevents the series to be drawn.

However, I am quite confident about my data, because, first of all, it works the first time I add it, and then, I added for debugging purposes:

```
    for (var j = 0; j < chart.series; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < chart.series[j]; k++) {
            if (!$.isNumeric(chart.series[j].data[k].value)) {alert("value error");}
            if (!$.isNumeric(chart.series[j].data[k].time)) {alert("time error");}
        }
    }
```

And it does not trigger.

I have tried adding it without removing it first, and it works well, so I can reasonably narrow the problem down to the remove part, but I don't understand what I go wrong.

I hope you guys can help me with this.

Have a nice day,

**UPDATE June 8th.**
I've been working on this most of the night, and I found some interesting things, comparing my fiddle with http://jsbin.com/fasamexehe/edit?js,output, by [ne8il](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944123/dimplejs-toggling-the-display-of-a-series-selectively), which does almost the same thing, but works.

- Whether the data is defined at chart creation or within the serie has no influence.
- The real problem lies within the 'dimple-plot-line' choice. Indeed, as show in this new fiddle: http://jsbin.com/fasamexehe/edit?js,output, if it is replaced by 'dimple-plot-bubble', with the same code, it works.

Now the question becomes: *Why does it work with bubbles and not with line?*

Comment: It would be easier to help if you put together your code into a working jsfiddle.

Comment: Sure thing. I edited the main post with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it.

A dimple-plot-line creates two kinds of objects in the svg:

- circle to represent data points, with opacity 0.
- path to connect them, which is visible.

But, the array `serie.shapes` only contains the latter. Therefore, if the serie is removed using `serie.shapes.remove`, the circles remain in the chart, and, during the next attempt to build the chart, they get in the way.

The solution to properly remove a `dimple-plot-line` is to use a d3 selector to get all the involved shapes, and remove them. Hence the final solution, with i the index of the series to be deleted:

```
d3.selectAll(".dimple-series-" + i).remove();
```

Here is a corrected version of the fiddle in the initial question: http://jsbin.com/qororekoqe/edit?js,output

I hope it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a line plot using version dimple.v2.1.6 - the line plots shows up fine. However, the chart does not work after upgrading to dimple.v2.3.0.min.js.  Similar error message.

Switched chart type to dimple.plot.bubble. Effect: No errors. All elements show correctly, but as bubbles.